# Importing materialdesignicons package in ReactJS & Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I am trying to add material design icons into my project via the npm "mdi" package. but I have issues.

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

var config = {
  entry: [
      'webpack/hot/dev-server',
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/',
      APP_DIR + '/index.jsx'
  ],
  output: {
      path: BUILD_DIR,
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      publicPath : '/'
  },
  devServer : {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      contentBase: 'src/public/'
  },
  module: {
      loaders : [            
          {
              test : /\.jsx?/,
              include : APP_DIR,
              loader : ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader']
          },
          {
              test: /\.s?css$/,
              loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
          },
          {
              test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\??\#?v=[.0-9]+)?$/,
              loader: 'file-loader?name=/fonts/[name].[ext]',
          }
      ]
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
};

//dev server

module.exports = config;
```

my App components calls the main scss file

```
import './scss/App.scss';
```

then in that App.scss file, I import a settings.scss and the materialdesignicons.scss file

settings.scss

```
$mdi-font-path: "fonts/";
```

App.scss

```
@import "./settings.scss";
@import '~mdi/scss/materialdesignicons.scss';
```

the project is imported via the main.scss file.

settings.scss

```
$mdi-font-path: "fonts/";
```

whenever I try to build, I get an error with it trying to figure out how to handle the webfont items.

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/scss/App.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './fonts//materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?v=1.9.32' in '/<path>/app/src/scss'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/scss/App.scss 7:129-189
 @ ./src/scss/App.scss
 @ ./src/App.jsx
 @ ./src/index.jsx
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/ ./src/index.jsx
```

I thought that the file-loader would handle those files. It seems that maybe since it's importing the scss file, it doesn't use the file loader part, and instead tries to use the sass/css loaders.

I'm trying to figure out how this should be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My approach consists of three steps:

1. to install material-design-icons package

   ```
   npm install material-design-icons
   ```
2. to import material-icons.css file into .less or .scss file/ project

   ```
   @import "~/node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css";
   ```
3. to include recommended code into the reactjs .js file/ project

   ```
   <i className='material-icons' style={{fontSize: '36px'}}>close</i>
   ```

Answer (score 7):

The file-loader does hadle those files. The Issue you have is that the file could not be found, and therefore it never gets to the file-loader.

materialdesignicons-webfont.eot is part of your node_modules, but when I think right now it is expected to be at ./app/src/scss/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot

I would expect this to work if you just remove your own definiton of $mdi-font-path.

UPDATE:

```
$mdi-font-path: '~mdi/fonts/';
@import '~mdi/scss/materialdesignicons';
```

Comment: I tried just removing $mdi-font-path and leaving it at the default '../fonts', which is what it has. I also import the node_module scss mdi file, via my own scss file.  I think i've gotten it to work if i do a 'require' inside the jsx file. I'd like to just get this done via scss since it makes more sense to me......   

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/scss/App.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?v=1.9.32' in '<my-comuters-path>/my-react-app/src/scss'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/scss/App.scss 7:129-189`

Comment: I've just tried it at my place and also ran into some issues. but this way it works just fine. give it a shot:


$mdi-font-path: '~mdi/fonts/';
@import '~mdi/scss/materialdesignicons';

Comment: Aha! I'll try that. I now see the issue. Still wrapping my head around this. But I believe I get it now.

Comment: brother. this worked. thank you very much.

I also found another issue. in my 'file-loader', I was passing the 'name' parameter. but if you look at my example, I had "'file-loader?name=/fonts/[name].[ext]'".  I had a forward slash before the 'fonts' folder. this made things not be where they should.

I added the new sass variable you gave me, and removed that forward slash and boom.

Comment: `$mdi-font-path:` - Setting the variable path concept was the missing piece when referencing font/icon libraries for me. In my case I need to define `$material-design-icons-font-directory-path` because `@import '~material-design-icons-iconfont/src/material-design-icons.scss';` was referencing it.